# batch sqlcmd using greater than / less than operands

Tags: batch-file, sqlcmd, operations

I am trying to generate a pretty basic SQL output data set using SQLCMD in a batch process where the content is filtered by the date of each record being between two values populated in a separate work file. Those values were loaded into the variables in a prior step in the batch file. If I use the operations > or < I get an error stating 'An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near AND'. If I change the operations to = or != it processes without error and I get appropariate results in the output data set.

I have searched for documents and examples that provide the proper sytax for using operations within an SQLCMD batch command and so far none have mentioned > or <. How do I specify those compares or are they not possible in this situation? Is the issue the data type of the contents of the operands?

```
SET OutputFile=%reports%\MD.SPCREQ01.%CompNum%.%yyyymmdd%_%hhmmss%.txt

sqlcmd -S %DBServerName% -d %DatabaseName% -o %OutputFile% -Q ^
"Select ^
FROM_NPA + '/' + FROM_NXX + '-' + FROM_NUMBER AS ""From Number"" ^
FROM dbo.MACC128 ^
WHERE CALL_YY + CALL_MM + CALL_DD >= '%FROM-CUT%' ^
AND CALL_YY + CALL_MM + CALL_DD <= '%TO-CUT%' ^
ORDER by CALL_YY, CALL_MM, CALL_DD, CONNECT_TIME_HH, CONNECT_TIME_MM, CONNECT_TIME_SS "
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<` and `>` characters are cmd.exe redirection operators - they must be either quoted or escaped (from a cmd.exe perspective). Your code does neither.

You do have quotes around your statement, but the leading quote is at the beginning of the line, and the end of the prior line ends with `^` line continuation. There is a quirk in the cmd.exe parser that causes the first character on the continued line to be escaped.

Your command is equivalent to:

```
sqlcmd -S %DBServerName% -d %DatabaseName% -o %OutputFile% -Q ^"Select FROM_NPA + '/' + FROM_NXX + '-' + FROM_NUMBER AS ""From Number"" FROM dbo.MACC128 WHERE CALL_YY + CALL_MM + CALL_DD >= '%FROM-CUT%' AND CALL_YY + CALL_MM + CALL_DD <= '%TO-CUT%' ORDER by CALL_YY, CALL_MM, CALL_DD, CONNECT_TIME_HH, CONNECT_TIME_MM, CONNECT_TIME_SS "
```

The quote is escaped, so it does not function as a quote during cmd.exe parsing.

You can fix your code by escaping `<` and `>` as `^<` and `^>`.

It will not work to modify your command so that the quote is not escaped because you cannot continue a line while the text is quoted.

You could put everything on one line and remove all `^`, but that is ugly.

I think the best solution is to put your command into a stand-alone .SQL file, and use the `-i` option to run the file instead of `-Q` to specify a command line query.

Comment: thank you, that helped me executing `sqlcmd` containing "<" via saltstack

Answer (score 0):

When I invoke your script (after changing `sqlcmd` to `echo`), I see that the ge (`>=`) and le (`<=`) are getting interpreted by the shell (emphasis added):

> echo -S  -d  -o \MD.SPCREQ01.._.txt -Q "Select FROM_NPA + '/' + FROM_NXX + '-' + FROM_NUMBER AS ""From Number"" FROM dbo.MACC128 WHERE CALL_YY + CALL_MM + CALL_DD AND CALL_YY + CALL_MM + CALL_DD ORDER by CALL_YY, CALL_MM, CALL_DD, CONNECT_TIME_HH, CONNECT_TIME_MM, CONNECT_TIME_SS " ***1>'' 0<''***

I suspect that CMD doesn't completely support multi-line strings like any sensible "language." You'll probably have to massage the content of the strings to make it work.

Try escaping the gt and lt symbols.

```
SET OutputFile=%reports%\MD.SPCREQ01.%CompNum%.%yyyymmdd%_%hhmmss%.txt

sqlcmd -S %DBServerName% -d %DatabaseName% -o %OutputFile% -Q ^
"Select ^
FROM_NPA + '/' + FROM_NXX + '-' + FROM_NUMBER AS ""From Number"" ^
FROM dbo.MACC128 ^
WHERE CALL_YY + CALL_MM + CALL_DD ^>= '%FROM-CUT%' ^
AND CALL_YY + CALL_MM + CALL_DD ^<= '%TO-CUT%' ^
ORDER by CALL_YY, CALL_MM, CALL_DD, CONNECT_TIME_HH, CONNECT_TIME_MM, CONNECT_TIME_SS "
```

When I run this (`echo`ing instead), I see the ge and le.